# Disable typing 0 (zero) at first character position

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a Jquery numeric plugin that only allows numeric values to be typed in an input

```
$("#tbQuan").numeric();
```

In addition to what this plugin is doing I need to disable typyng '0' (zero) at the first character position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing. I'm a Jquery nube. Same goes for javascript

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){ 
   if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c4L6t/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. This is almost perfect since the zero appears for a second. I would have preferred for zero not to appear at all. I'll accept as an answer since it gets the job done.

Comment: @boruchsiper - Check my edited answer, it is even more better. Now you will not see 0 at all.

Comment: Type something like 'asdf' goto position 0 and type zero :)

Comment: the above code works as it should ''BUT" if you select all and then press 0 it accepts the input - for that i implemented an additional charAt(0) check condition..to be in the safe side

Answer (score 2):

For the keyUp event

```
$('.numeric').keyup(function(event) {

var currentVal = $(this).val();

if (currentVal.length == 1 && (event.which == 48 || event.which == 96)) {
  currentVal = currentVal.slice(0, -1);
}
$(this).val(currentVal);
```

});

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/shanikayrs/3pLvyvhv/)

- make sure to add both 48 and 96 events to support number pad 0 and keyboard 0.
- adding this way, user get to know that leading zeros are not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```
$("#tbQuan").numeric().keyup(function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    while (val.substring(0, 1) === '0') {   //First character is a '0'.
        val = val.substring(1);             //Trim the leading '0'
    }
    $(this).val(val);   //update input with new value
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost works. The problem is that it allows to enter 0 at first position and replaces the next time another number is typed. I need to disable typing 0 at first position all together.

Comment: Whoops! Try the keyup event instead. Modified answer to reflect that. Sorry to say that you cannot use JavaScript to disable certain keys on the keyboard as that goes well beyond the scope of JavaScript. You can try to sanitize the input (which is what this script is doing).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like @ShankarSangoli beat you to the chase with a similar solution so I accepted his answer first. Though I have the same issue with his answer as with yours. The 0 appears for a moment before getting erased. I would have preferred for zero not to appear at all,

Comment: I would disagree with you on disabling certain keys in JavaScript. The numeric plugin I'm using does just that for none numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by trying something like this:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
   if ( $(this).val().length === 1 && $(this).val() === 0 ){
      alert('No leading zeroes!');
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I need. Just that I don't need it to alert, I just want for the keydown not to happen at all just like one can't type none numeric values with the numeric plugin.

Answer (score 0):

if textbox in masked then:::

```
$('#numeric').keyup(function(event) {

    var currentVal = $(this).val();

    if (currentVal.substring(0, 1) === '0' && (event.which == 48 || event.which == 96)) {

      currentVal=currentVal.substring(1);
    }
    $(this).val(currentVal);
  });
```

OR *******************************

```
$("#numeric").keyup("input propertychange paste", function (e) {
var val = $(this).val()
var reg = /^0/gi;
if (val.match(reg)) {
    $(this).val(val.replace(reg, ""));
    alert("Please phone number first character bla blaa not 0!");
    $(this).mask("999 999-9999");

}
```

});

---

[First Sample DEMO :](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLvyvhv/10)

[Second Sample DEMO :](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLvyvhv/24)