# How To Validate Text Field not accept 0 as First digit and Whole digit using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How To Validate Text Field not accept 0 as First digit and Whole digit using Javascript. for example, Its should not accept

```
0,00,000,01,02,001 and so on
```

It will accept

```
10,100,10000 and so on
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106603/disable-typing-0-zero-at-first-character-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first character of the entered string/value, and check with 0, on which event you want to check, modify accordingly.

```
<input id="myId" value="0123" />
$('#myId').blur(function(e){ 
var first_char = $("#myId").val().substring(0, 1);
  if (first_char == 0){
   return false;
   }
});
```

Hope this helps

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myId').blur(function(e){ 
var first_char = $("#myId").val().substring(0, 1);
  if (first_char == 0){
   alert('first character is 0');
   }else{
   alert('first character is not 0');
   }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myId" value="0123" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This Exactly I want.

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Blur may not be the best/only event you want to attach this to. It doesn't always fire. You want to do proper validation on form submit too.